# How to read comments from google sheet cells?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gspread

I want to access data from the commented cell in google sheets. I have done some work, and able to access the value in the cell.

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import json

scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('WorkSheet001-4d8ce6dbd79f.json', scope)

gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
wks = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ME7WatXOmSEytwu7Qxem-a6BzCew36RKmD7KdhKMwbA/edit#gid=0').sheet1

print(wks.cell(2, 2).value)

print(wks.get_all_records())
```

I want data from the commented cell. want to access data like it's time, date and comment on the cell etc

```
[{'name': 'Naresh', 'technology': 'Php'}, {'name': 'kuldeep', 'technology': 'python'}]
```

Comment: Have you read [this question and topmost answer for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18753147/getting-comments-from-range-in-google-script)? Do you mean notes instead of comments?

Answer (score 0):

You could try Sheetfu library for this type of task, specifically using the table module.

```
from sheetfu import Table

spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp('path/to/secret.json').open_by_id('<insert spreadsheet id here>')
data_range = spreadsheet.get_sheet_by_name('people').get_data_range()

table = Table(data_range, notes=True)

for item in table:
    if item.get_field_note('name'):
        # DO SOMETHING IF THERE IS A NOTE ON FIELD NAME
        item.set_field_note('name', 'your note')

table.commit()
```